# How do I make dygraph expand to fill height on div

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dygraphs

I am unable to get DyGraph to render to the correct height. My ideal is for graph to be 100% of main browser area height.

i.e. I would like it to fill all space between navbar and footer.

With set-up below I get a graph but it is just a single horizontal line. I don't want to specify a px height as I would like to fill whatever room is available.

_PnlDyGraph.cshtml:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dygraph-combined-dev.js"></script>
<h1>Title</h1>
<div id="mygrapharea" style="width: 100%; height:100%;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    @{
        string txtER = (string)Session["PnlDataForChart"];
            <text>
               var dataT = "@txtER"
            </text>
     }
    g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("mygrapharea"),
                dataT 
        );
</script>
```

_Traders.cshtml:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Employee/_PnlDyGraph.cshtml")
    </div>
</div>
```

_Layoutcshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    @*<title>@ViewBag.Title - Platform</title>*@
    <title>Platform</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <img src="~/Images/Banner_Front.png" alt="Banner" style="width:300px;height:50px;"/>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Traders", "Traders", "Traders")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()

        <hr />
        <footer>
            @*<p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year</p>*@
        </footer>
    </div>

    @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")*@
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: based on div height its get size and if you resize your page then DyGraph does not resize automatically for that you should use resize() method of DyGraph. like gygraph set variable is g1 then g1.resize(); it work on my application

Comment: I included after    <br>

`g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("mygrapharea"),
                dataT 
        ); g.resize();`

Comment: and the problem is still the same

Answer (score 3):

you should write this div in another div and specified div height in pixel and in inner div you will specified in percentage.

> Without content, the height has no value to calculate the percentage of. The width, however, will take the percentage from the DOM, if no parent is specified.

for example.

```
<div id="parent" style="width:100px;height:1000px;background-color:orange">
  <div id="mygrapharea" style="width:100px;height:100%;  background-color:blue"></div>
</div>
```

i hope it will helps you

Comment: You likely want the div and the paragraph in it to have a 100% height, but that div actually has two parent elements: <body> and <html>. In order to define the height of the div to a relative height, you must set the height of the body and html elements as well. So you would need to use CSS to set the height of not only the div, but also the body and html elements. This can be a challenge, since you can quickly get overwhelmed with everything being set to 100% height, only to achieve this desired effect.